# How to get php page to receive ajax post from html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a very simple form that has an input field for first name. I captured the form data and transmitted it via ajax to a PHP page using the standard jQuery posting method. However, I am not able at all get any responses from the PHP page that any data was captured on the server-side. I am not sure what I have done wrong or what is missing.

Here is my code.

Form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label for="firstName">First name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name">
<div class="d-none" id="firstName_feedback">
<p>Please enter a first name.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Jquery Ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
var formData = $("form").serialize();
console.log(formData); 
$.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
url: 'form.php', 
data: formData, 
dataType: 'json', 
encode: true    
   })
.done(function(data) {
 console.log(data); 
 });
 event.preventDefault();
 });

 });


</script>
```

And here is my PHP page:

```
if(isset($_POST['formData']))    
$ajaxData = ($_POST['formData']); 
echo $ajaxData;
{
}
```

Comment: `formData` is the name of the variable you serialized your inputs into.  It is not the query param name.  The query param names will be whatever the input names in you form were.  In this example, `$_POST['firstName']` would be present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Ajax function, you're passing the contents of `formData` to the server, though not as `formData` but as their original input name.

In this case, you have:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name">
```

The input's name is firstName, so you need to call `$_POST['firstName']` instead of `$_POST['formData']`.

```
if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
    $ajaxData = $_POST['firstName'];
    echo $ajaxData;
}
```

The same applies for any other field you would have in your form, so for example, having another input with the name `lastName` means you'd have to call `$_POST['lastName']` to access it.

There were also some misplaced brackets and parentheses in the PHP code which I accommodated above.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ data is the name of the field for `$.ajax` to specify the post data ,not the name of any partciular post data.  form parameters would have the `name` of the input element from the form, so `$_POST['firstName']`

Comment: My bad, I mixed up some concepts, you're right about that. Edited the post accordingly.