# How to troubleshoot an AJAX call via jQuery to a PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to get help for the second time in two days. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506725/how-to-get-php-page-to-receive-ajax-post-from-html-page) is my previous question.

I have a very simple form that has one input field in it for First Name. The form was created using Bootstrap 4. Here is the bare HTML code:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
<label for="firstName">First name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="First name">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to capture the value of the firstName input field and send it as string to my PHP page via the jQuery ajax method. At the PHP page, all what I wanted to do at the moment is to save it to a variable and echo the value of that variable back to the HTML page without refreshing the page.

I failed to do so after I tried everything that I know. Not sure what I am doing wrong and where to go from here.

Here is my ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(event) {
var formData = {
var formData = $("form").serialize();
console.log(formData); 
$.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
url: 'form.php', 
data: formData, 
dataType: 'json', 
encode: true        
})
.done(function(data) {
console.log(data); 
});
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

And,

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
$ajaxData = $_POST['firstName'];
echo $ajaxData;
}
?>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [How to get php page to receive ajax post from html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506725/how-to-get-php-page-to-receive-ajax-post-from-html-page). Please do not ask a questions in duplicate.

Comment: I have downvoted this question. The original version reflected rather a lot of entitlement (_I will try again here otherwise I will give up on this site for help_), and I think feedback is in order. When people help here, they are doing it in their free time, and thus any assistance at all is a kindness. It does not come with a money-back guarantee, and there is no Complaints Department.

Comment: When someone writes code for you and presents it in an answer, it is still your responsibility to (a) liaise with them if it does not work, (b) describe in what way it does not work, (c) make useful observations about what expected behaviour does not happen, or what unexpected behaviour does happen; (d) use the evidence before you for new avenues of independent research. Remember that you are the only person who can see your screen, and so you are in the best position to help people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @halfer. Thank you for your feedback. I like to clarify the technical issue that was the heart of the problem for others to learn from or avoid in the future. The JQUERY DataType code in the ajax call is 1) optional and, 2) is what is expected from the server. As it turned out we have no control over what we can fetch back from the server as DataType. That was my problem, the server was sending back text, and I was asking to get back JSON. Hence, ajax communication, failed. Once I deleted the DataType line in the code, or changed the DataType to 'text', communication succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the Javascript.

This line `var formData = {` should not be there.

As you are specifying that you are [expecting](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) `json` returned from the server in `dataType: 'json'` you could update the php part to:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($_POST['firstName']);
    exit;
}
```